# undefined error in protractor on using a gettext() function and using it in other file

Tags: javascript, protractor, angular-promise

I have written a utility function in InputBoxActions.js file for getting a text from the input field in protractor as as :

```
   this.getTextFromInputBox = function (element) {
        if (typeof element !== 'undefined') {
            element.isDisplayed().then(function () {
                element.isEnabled().then(function () {

                    element.getText().then(function(text){
                        return text;
                    })


                });
            });
        }
    };
```

However , on using the same function in the test spec file, i am getting the value of the text as undefined. Here i am calling the function as :

```
browserActions.goto(url);
      var searchElement = findElements.byXpath("//input[@type='search']");
      inputBoxActions.type(searchElement, 'angular');
      var text = inputBoxActions.getTextFromInputBox(searchElement);
      console.log(text);
```

Result i am getting is :

```
Started
undefined
(node:1412) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 6.082 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your innermost return statement is only returning the value to the function that calls it and then unused.

```
-> element.getText().then(function(text){
     return text;
   });
```

You need to return all the nested then's like so if you want to achieve this in this way.

```
this.getTextFromInputBox = function (element) {
    if (typeof element !== 'undefined') {
        return element.isDisplayed().then(function () {
            return element.isEnabled().then(function () {
                return element.getText().then(function (text) {
                    return text;
                })
            });
        });
    }else{
        throw new Error(`${element} is undefined`);
    }
};
```

Imagine a line of guys who hand off some work to each other to complete. Your guy at the end is doing the work but not passing it back up the line to the boss where it is needed.